# Controls on a tabpage (tab control) that's not visible return Visible = false

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a tab control in a windows form. It's working great, except for the following example. When I have `tabpage2` selected, all controls on `tabpage1` return their `visible` property as FALSE which actually is untrue because they are all set to `visible = false`.

I suppose it's because the `tabpage1` is set to `visible = false` so all child controls inherit FALSE.

Of course if `tabpage1` is selected, then all controls return the correct value for the visible property.

There must be a work around. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Why would you want a workaround to this? The controls are not visible when their parent tab page is not visible. That is the same rules as and other window. Perhaps if you told us what you're trying to accomplish we could suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: If a control's `visible` property is set to false, naturally it will return false when checking that property. Am I misreading?

Comment: Sure ... its a tab control with a few tabpages..each tabpages has a number of controls on there.. I need to check if an ALERT panel that i have is visible .. if it is then i fail the validation routine that i run... but i am checking the visible property of the alert panel when tabpage2 is open and its on tabpage1 ... if that makes sense

Comment: @JYelton, the viisible property of a control is not false but becasue the tabpage is not visible it returns false

Comment: I see what you mean. The property is true when you created the control; however the tab control changes it during execution of the program, when the tab page is not selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Visible` property of your panel is not behaving in the way you expect, try setting the Panel's `Tag` property to something or other instead, and use that to determine whether or not to fail the validation.

Answer (score 11):

The Visible property is a bit special, its getter doesn't return the value you assigned.  It tells you if the control is *actually visible*.  Which it is not if it is placed on a tab page that isn't selected.  This is by design.

Getting the actual "intends to be visible" state isn't supported.  You'd get it out of GetState(2) but that's an internal method.  If you're really desperate then you could use Reflection.  But the proper way is to just keep track of it yourself.

Comment: +1 This sheds light on what's actually going on with this property, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Making a small project to confirm this, if you check the `Visible` property of any control on a tab page that is *not* currently selected, it will return false, because the control is *not* visible.

If you are trying to determine which tab page a user is currently viewing, you may be better off to check the `SelectedTab` or `SelectedIndex` property of the TabControl.

Comment: No i am trying to check if a panel is visible=true ..this means i have an error :-)    maybe i should just use a class level bool variable instead....

Comment: A panel on the first tab page will also have its visible property set to false if that tab page is no longer selected. (Make sure you are using `==` instead of `=` for equality checking.) If you are setting that panel's visibility programmatically, then you can't rely on its setting while its parent tabpage is no longer active. You'll want to create a separate variable as you suggested.